# Match rows that are duplicate in part (and delete all but the oldest one)

Tags: php, mysql

I use an email autoresponder software that assigns contacts (i.e. people, with name, email address, and so on) to autoresponders (i.e. sequences of messages that they have subscribed to).

It so happens that some people are subscribed to the same autoresponder twice.

The table then looks like this:

```
id    contact_id    autoresponder_id    stamp_subscribe    other_stuff
1     1             5                   1430400000         slkdfj
2     2             5                   1430402085         oweuoe
3     1             5                   1430402085         iclksls
```

I am trying to find a MySQL query that...

1. Matches all entries where the same contact_id is assigned to autoresponder_id = "5" twice or more, ignoring all other_stuff (in the example: lines ID 1 and ID 3)
2. Of all those found for any contact_id, deletes all but the oldest one (i.e. that with the lowest stamp_subscribe value; in the example: line ID 3 would be removed, leaving the older entry of line ID 1)

Comment: submit your code, which u tried from yourself

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sub query to find all the first records for a contact_id / autoresponder_id, and join that sub query with a LEFT OUTER JOIN to your main table. Then delete all the rows where there is no matching record.

```
DELETE a
FROM sometable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT contact_id, autoresponder_id, MIN(id) AS id
        FROM sometable
        GROUP BY contact_id, autoresponder_id
    ) sub0
) b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Note, deletes like this make me very nervous due to the potential for a minor mistake to result in lots of data being deleted.